# Start screen with commands for different windows

Tags: gnu-screen

How can I start gnu screen with several different commands in several different windows?

i.e., (pseudocode)

```
screen -window1="ping google.com" -window2="vim ~/secret_document.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a screen config file, e.g.

```
screen -t "window1" ping google.com
screen -t "window2" vim ~/secret_document.txt
```

Then start screen with the config file:

```
screen -c configfile
```